# Why does "\t" in a Text widget create a new line?

Tags: flutter

I have added `\t` to add spacing in a `Text` widget, but it moved to the next line.

```
 child: new Text(
          "+\tAdd to-do",
          style: new TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 20.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
            letterSpacing: 0.3,
          ),
        ),
```

[image]

Comment: but this works sometimes and sometimes it doesnt

Answer (score 2):

\t stands for tab and because there is not enough space your text is pushed to the next line which in this case gives you a similar effect to using \n

Answer (score 0):

Seems like due to **padding** or something, there is no enough space to fit "+ \t Add to-do". Hence the rest of the text is wrapping down.

Try to reduce the parent padding.

Answer (score 0):

The response of @buli1212 is right.
But, I recommend use icon instead of text '+', like this code:

```dart
      FloatingActionButton.extended(
        onPressed: () {},
        icon: Icon(Icons.add),
        label: Text('Add to-do', style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 20.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
            letterSpacing: 0.3,
          ),
        ),
      );
```

Best regards